# SQL - Insert multiple rows based on one record with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert, bulkinsert

I need to insert multiple rows based on one record in Table A to Table B. The query needs to grab each day from the start and end date in Table A and check if it is working day. If it's non-working days(weekends), it will not insert into Table B.

Scenario as below:

```
Table A:

+ LID + Start_Date +  End_Date  +  Working_Day  + Total_Days
------------------------------------------------------------
| 101 | 1-Jan-18   | 5-Jan-2018 |       Yes     |     5    |


Table B (Expected Result):

+ LID + Start_Date +  End_Date  +
---------------------------------
| 101 | 1-Jan-18   | 1-Jan-2018 |
| 101 | 2-Jan-18   | 2-Jan-2018 |
| 101 | 3-Jan-18   | 3-Jan-2018 |
| 101 | 4-Jan-18   | 4-Jan-2018 |
| 101 | 5-Jan-18   | 5-Jan-2018 |
```

Comment: Can you give an example of "non-working days"?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can expand the data using a recursive CTE and then filter out the weekend days:

```
with cte as (
      select ltd, start_date, end_date, 
      from a
      union all
      select ltd, date_add(day, 1, start_date), end_date
      from cte
      where start_date < end_date
     )
select ltd, start_date, end_date
from cte
where datename(weekday, start_date) not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday');
```

Comment: Hi, I tried out the query. It works. However, some of the results i get have additional day. Example, from a date range of 1-Jan to 10-Jan. There's an extra day of 11-Jan. Please assist. Thank you.

Comment: @TheLegend28 . . . That just might be an interpretation of whether the last day is included in the range or not.  For this query, the last day is included.

Comment: Sorry, i don't quite get it. How does including last day causes an extra day? How does 11-Jan appear when when my last day is 10-Jan?

Comment: @TheLegend28 . . . You can change the condition to `dateadd(day, 1, start_date) < end_date`.